# zend framework - sort elements in subform

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have form with 3 subforms. My question is how can I sort elements within one subform. Each element has it's own order number. I tried to call _sort method like:

```
   $subform->_sort();
```

But it doesn't work. So, how can I order elements?

Comment: It looks like the problem is solved. For displaying form elements in right order I should use getElementsAndSubFormsOrdered() instead of getElements()

Comment: post it as an answe rand accept it! That way you help others too.

Answer (score 2):

For displaying form elements in right order you should use `getElementsAndSubFormsOrdered()` instead of `getElements()`